# probelma con woocommerce no se si a alguien le a pasado?

Tags: wordpress

Cronograma de depósitos
La programación de depósitos no está disponible actualmente para tu tienda.
Cuenta bancaria de depósito
Administre y actualice la información de su cuenta de depósito para recibir pagos y depósitos. Administrar en Stripe(se abre en una nueva pestaña)

Establezca su nivel de riesgo de pago
Se ha producido un error al recuperar la configuración de protección contra fraudes. Actualice la página para volver a intentarlo.

Básico
Proporciona el nivel básico de protección de la plataforma.

Avanzado

Le permite ajustar el nivel de filtrado de acuerdo con las necesidades de su negocio.

es en la casilla de pagos...

e intentado en stripe y sale todo bien no se q aser